# Frame gets drastically decreased when Image Processing is done using OpenCV in Visual Studio C++

Tags: python, c++, visual-studio, opencv

I am using Visual Studio 2017 and OpenCV 3.1. Without any Image Processing the frame rate is very good, but as soon as I do Image Processing, as little as convert to gray scale image and apply gaussian blur, frame rate just plummets. The same code in Python runs almost at real time frame rate(Shouldn't C++ be faster than Python). Here is my code.

```
#include "opencv2\core\core.hpp"
#include "opencv2\imgproc\imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include <iostream>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;
Mat processed_frame;

Mat imageProcessing(Mat frame_proc) {
  cvtColor(frame_proc, processed_frame, COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
  medianBlur(processed_frame, processed_frame, 5);
  GaussianBlur(processed_frame, processed_frame, Size(21, 21), 0);
  threshold(processed_frame, processed_frame, 127, 255, 0);
  cv::Mat structuringElement5x5 = cv::getStructuringElement(cv::MORPH_RECT, cv::Size(5, 5));
  for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    cv::dilate(processed_frame, processed_frame, structuringElement5x5);
  }
  for (unsigned int j = 1; j < 2; j++) {
    erode(processed_frame, processed_frame, structuringElement5x5);
  }
  return (processed_frame);
}

int main() {
  Mat frame;
  Mat img3;
  VideoCapture cap("/path/to/Video/File");

  if (!cap.isOpened()) {
    cout << "Cannot open file" << endl;
    return -1;  
  }
  bool bSuccess = cap.read(frame);
  while (bSuccess) {
    cap >> frame;
    frame = imageProcessing(frame);*IF I COMMENT THIS LINE, FRAME RATE IS VERY GOOD
    imshow("VideoCapture", frame);
    cap.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FPS, 25);
    if (waitKey(1) == 27) {
        break;
    }
  }
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you running the code in `Debug` mode? Also, the frame returned by the `cap` object should not be modified in any case. A separate `Mat` must be allocated for the output of `imageProcessing` function.

Comment: Yes I am running it in Debug mode, so I should create a `frame.clone` and then apply Image Processing to it??

Comment: Created a copy of frame and then applied Image Processing to it, still not much difference in frame rate.

Comment: You should run it in `Release` mode to measure actual performance.

Comment: @sgarizvi It works in Release mode, but I have a qustion, what if I wanted to deploy this in Android(C++ Support), what will be performance? Also the frame rate in Release Mode has improved, but still not as same as Python.

Comment: Can you share the python code to confirm if there is a possible optimization being done?